# On iPhone, how to make the keyboard show numbers above the letters?

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

On iPhone, is there a way to make the keyboard show numbers above the letters, like computer keyboards? It seems that the keyboard type doesn't provide that.

I know that this will need more space for the keyboard. I can afford that.

Answer (score 2):

By default, no, this is not possible. However, Apple provides a way for developers to attach views to the keyboard. Take a look at [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputAccessoryView) and [`inputAccessoryViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputAccessoryViewController), both `UIResponder` properties, these are the properties that are used to do this.

Comment: Do I need to subclass the UITextField?

Comment: @zhoudu No, the properties are `readwrite` on `UITextField`. You can take a look at [this project](https://github.com/tnantoka/EDHInputAccessoryView) for example to get an idea of how to implement something like this.